# XAML TextBox binding to Property inside of a Class

Tags: vb.net, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Okay, so I'm trying to setup a page in the Windows Phone app that will have a LongListSelector with 2 groups, and within each group there are different types of data that can be displayed. I was able to setup a TemplateSelector that chooses the right data template for the different types of objects but I can't seem to drill down to the right binding path for the actual values in the datasource. I'll try to post all the relevant code to see if that will help

```
    'These are the classes that are used for the Datasource, there are 2 specific classes and then one class to use for the data source that will contain a type value and then one of the 2 specific classes
 Public Class ActionItemsClass
        Public Property type As String
        Public Property alertItem As AlertClass
        Public Property btrItem As BTRClass
    End Class

    Public Class AlertClass
        Public Property asOfDate As String
        Public Property subject As String
        Public Property text As String

    End Class

    Public Class BTRClass
        Public Property id As String
        Public Property policyID As String
        Public Property fromUser As String
        Public Property txnNumber As String
        Public Property createdDate As String
        Public Property contactID As String
        Public Property contactName As String
        Public Property productName As String
        Public Property investmentAmount As String
        Public Property btrNote As String
        Public Property currentStatus As String
        Public Property response As String

    End Class
```

And here's the XAML code for the template selection, and as you can see I've been trying a variety of methods to get the data to show (for now just one item from each class as a test) but so far the only thing that shows up is the Group headers and the datasource is being created without any issues

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="alertItem">
            <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding AlertClass}" Text="{Binding text}" Foreground="Red"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="btrItem">
            <TextBlock Text ="{Binding Path=btrItem.btrNote}" Foreground="Green"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="SelectingTemplate">
            <local:TemplateSelector AlertTemplate ="{StaticResource alertItem}"
                                    BTRTemplate="{StaticResource btrItem}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to bind the textblock like this

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding AlertClass.text}" Foreground="Red"/>
```

Comment: Actually I found the problem, I first needed to add a "Content={Binding}" to the SelectingTemplate and then alertItem.text Binding worked. Thanks.